# Cannot get spring email to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a spring email service for which I implemented the GOOF design pattern. I created an interface Email service as follows.

public interface EmailService {

```
public void sendFeedbackEmail(FeedbackPojo feedbackPojo);

public void sendGenericEmailMessage(SimpleMailMessage message);
```

}

Then I created an abstract class which extends this interface and implements one of it's overridden methods which is `sendFeedbackEmail(FeedBackPojo feedbackpojo)` The implementation of this abstract class is as follows.

```
public abstract class AbstractEmailService implements EmailService {

@Value("@{default.to.address}")
private String defaultToAddress ;

protected SimpleMailMessage preparedSimpleMailMessageFromFeedbackPojo(FeedbackPojo feedback){
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(defaultToAddress);
    message.setFrom(feedback.getEmail());
    message.setSubject("[Subscriber]: Feedback Received from"+ feedback.getFirstName()+" "+feedback.getLastName()+"!");
    message.setText(feedback.getFeedback());

    return message;
}

@Override
public void sendFeedbackEmail(FeedbackPojo feedbackPojo) {
    sendGenericEmailMessage(preparedSimpleMailMessageFromFeedbackPojo(feedbackPojo));
}
```

}

Then I created a class MockEmailService with the implementation of second method of the EmailService interface which is sendGenericEmail(SimpleMailMessage message) as follows

public class MockEmailService extends AbstractEmailService{

```
private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockEmailService.class);

@Override
public void sendGenericEmailMessage(SimpleMailMessage message) {
    System.out.println(message.toString());
}
```

}

Then I am creating an Autowired object of emailService in my controller class and simulating my emailservice as follows

```
@Controller
```

public class ContactController {

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactController.class);
public static final String FEEDBACK_MODEL_KEY="feedback";
private static final String CONTACT_US_VIEW_NAME="contact/contact";

@Autowired
private EmailService emailService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/contact",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getContact(ModelMap model){
    FeedbackPojo feedbackPojo = new FeedbackPojo();
    model.addAttribute(ContactController.FEEDBACK_MODEL_KEY,feedbackPojo);
    return ContactController.CONTACT_US_VIEW_NAME;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/contact",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postContact(@ModelAttribute(FEEDBACK_MODEL_KEY) FeedbackPojo feedback){
    log.debug("Feedback content {}",feedback);
    emailService.sendFeedbackEmail(feedback);
    return ContactController.CONTACT_US_VIEW_NAME;
}
```

}

However, when I try to run my application the application terminates and the error I receive is as follows

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.subscriptionservice.backend.service.EmailService com.subscriptionservice.web.controllers.ContactController.emailService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.subscriptionservice.backend.service.EmailService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Can someone please point out the issue in my implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.subscriptionservice.backend.service.EmailService] found for
>   dependency

As far as I see, you haven't introduced an instance of your interface `EmailService` into the collection of Spring-managed beans.

Try annotating (stereotyping) the `MockEmailService` with `@Service`.

Also...

- Make sure you have `component-scan` defined somewhere in a manner that will include the package where `MockEmailService` resides.
- Do you intend that the `MockEmailService` will permanently implement the contract of `EmailService` in your application?  (Based on the name, I wouldn't guess so.)  If `MockEmailService` is intended only for certain circumstances -- such as non-production deployments or testing -- you may need a more flexible system for defining or wiring your beans.  There are many options, such as [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked after annotating the MockEmailService. Yes, MockEmailService is for non-production deployments. I am maintaining different spring profiles.